# Insert new column and lost data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

To add a new column to the table I double click on the table's name in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 and then right click to insert a new column. But the problem is that the new column is gone after I have run my aplication with a connection with the database.

All new data added to the database is gone after I shut down Visual Studio. But the data is in the database while I use the application, because I can load and see the new data I just added. The only data that are left are the data I added while I created the database and table in Visual Studio.

I'm using a mdf file. I have checked if the mdf file is in Bin/Debug. One thing that is strange is that there a two .mdf databases in the Server Explorer .mdf and .mdf1. It's the last one I have been trying to alter.

What could be wrong? A helping hand is appreciated! I need to hand in this task as soon as possible to my teacher. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using T-sql:

```
Alter table table1 add col1 datatype.
```

Then try to insert data into it:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2...)
VALUES(v1,v2...)
```

Then you try to test.